# Horizontal scroll UICollectionView has additional line spacing?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to use UICollectionView to make a table, when I set it to vertical scroll, everything is working great. 
But when I set it to horizontal scroll, it appears some additional line spacing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7536O.jpg

And this is what it working on vertical scroll(no spacing):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxFMy.jpg

Following is some setting about my Collection View:

[i.stack.imgur.com/aWGO3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWGO3.jpg)

[i.stack.imgur.com/vrbLp.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrbLp.jpg)

Is there any way to solve this? Thanks!

(Sorry for I can't post image and can't post more than 2 links, because it need more than 10 reputation..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection cell height is 80 and Screen height is 480 I guess, and there are 5 items showing vertically so remaining space(480-(80*5)) which is 80 is showing between items as 20 pixels. So you should either increase your cell size or adjust size of `UICollecttionView`.

Comment: Oh! Okay, now I understand how it working, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```